# Why i cannot display the result from firebase database in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdftM.png)

I have declare an id for tbody as table_body. I also plugin the jquery code. In my js file include javascript and jquery, not pure javascipt. So it affected the result?

```js
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('facility');
var query = firebaseRef.orderByKey();

query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var tb_name = snapshot.child('schedulename').val();
  var tb_time = snapshot.child('timesession').val();
  var tb_fees = snapshot.child('fees').val();

  console.log(snapshot.val());

  $("#table_body").append("<td><tr>" + tb_name + "</tr><tr>" + tb_time + "</tr><tr>" + tb_fees + "</tr></td>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
  <table border="2" style="color:#f2f2f2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Schedule</td>
        <td>Time Session</td>
        <td>Fees</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body"></tbody>
  <table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet is missing the reference to the Firebase SDK. Have you included that in your local copy?

Comment: Show me the result of the statement: `console.log(snapshot.val());`

Comment: There's no closing `</table>`

Comment: ok, i will edit the post to insert the result

Comment: after i added the closing but still not working